# gnupg: There is no assurance this key belongs to the named user

Tags: encryption, passwords, public-key-encryption, gnupg

I'm trying to use interesting password management [tool](http://www.passwordstore.org/) named Pass.

I did the following:

1. Installed gpg tool `$ sudo dnf install gpg`
2. Generated a key using `$ gpg --gen-key`
3. Typed `$ pass init "foobar id of my gpg key"` as stated [here](http://www.passwordstore.org/)
4. Got

`mkdir: created directory ‘/home/chichivica/.password-store/’ Password store initialized for foobar@email.com`

5. Tried to add a simple password

`$ pass insert foo Enter password for foo:  Retype password for foo:`

6. And there is the problem

`gpg: A45A123C: There is no assurance this key belongs to the named user gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: Unusable public key`

Could anyone give me some advice?

Comment: What is `gpg -K` printing?

Comment: @JensErat just this 

`/home/chichivica/.gnupg/secring.gpg

-----------------------------------

sec   2048R/96F0E0C0 2015-10-26
uid                  Ivan Talalaev (chichivica) <foo@bar.com>
ssb   2048R/76A1D91D 2015-10-26
`

Comment: Where in (6) is the ID A45A123C coming from? Your master key ID is another one.

Comment: @JensErat So, it's a question. Actually I do not know. I couldn't find any occurrences of this string!

Comment: Is it listed using `gpg --list-keys A45A123C`? What exactly did you specify in `pass init`? "foobar id" does not really explain what you have done.

Comment: @JensErat 1. `gpg --list-keys A45A123C` result: `gpg: error reading key: public key not found`   2.  As stated [here](http://www.passwordstore.org/) I passed in `pass init  "Ivan Talalaev (chichivica) <foo@bar.com>"`. Also I tried `pass init "foo@bar.com"` with the same result.

Comment: Try `pass init 96F0E0C0`.

Comment: @JensErat I have already try that. Exactly the same result :(

Comment: Hi @Ivan, I also encounter this problem today. Were you able to solve it, how did you do it? Thanks

Comment: It appears that --list-keys may not list encryption subkey IDs, but `gpg --list-keys --keyid-format long` does

Answer (score 378, accepted):

I had the same issue after copying my key pair from one machine to another. The solution for me was the set the trust level of the keys:

```
gpg --edit-key <KEY_ID>
gpg> trust
```

You will be asked to select the trust level from the following:

```
1 = I don't know or won't say
2 = I do NOT trust
3 = I trust marginally
4 = I trust fully
5 = I trust ultimately
m = back to the main menu
```

I selected 5 since I created the key so of course I trust it ultimately :). It will ask you to confirm your decision:

```
Your decision? 5
Do you really want to set this key to ultimate trust? (y/N) y
```

After confirming, quit with:

```
gpg> quit
```

You should then be able to encrypt using that key.

Comment: key_id is the mailid you have used

Comment: `gpg> quit` to exit.

Comment: or simply `gpg> q` also exits.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work for me. Still get the same message. I had a script that used a passwordless key to encrypt my duplicity backups. Looks like I have to accept unencrypted from now on. :(

Comment: i had to set the trust explicitly for the encryption ssb, i.e. select it first in the gpg prompt with `key <SSB_ID>` so that an asterisk appears next to it

Comment: Would it be still working if I select `1` for trust level?

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue in batch mode and adding the flag `--trust-model always` worked for me.

The full command for batch mode with Ultimate trust, non-interactive passphrase is as below:

`gpg --batch --trust-model always --recipient <recipient uid> --pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase <your passphrase> --encrypt-files *.*`