# Python GNUPG - Trust Imported Key?

Tags: python, gnupg, trust

Similar to this:
[gnupg: There is no assurance this key belongs to the named user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361068/gnupg-there-is-no-assurance-this-key-belongs-to-the-named-user)

But I want to set the trust level of an imported key pair within Python. Is this possible? And if so, how?

At the moment after trying to encrypt a file with the public key, I'm receiving the message:

```
"There is no assurance this key belongs to the named user\r\n[GNUPG:] INV_RECP 10 TestUser@Company.Com\r\n[GNUPG:] FAILURE sign-encrypt 53\r\ngpg: [stdin]: sign+encrypt failed: Unusable public key\r\n"
```

This is after running the following:

```
with open('Test.txt', 'rb') as f:
                status = gpg.encrypt_file(
                    f,sign=public_key_fingerprint,
                    recipients=private_key_recipient,
                    output = output_file
                )
```

status.status returns:

```
'invalid recipient'
```

EDIT:

```
private_key_recipient = 'TestUser@Company.Com'
```

Comment: can we see how you get `private_key_recipient` ?

Comment: @DashWinterson - That's actually obtained from a GCP secret JSON. It's a string of: 'TestUser@Company.Com'.

Comment: private_key_recipient should be a public GPG key iirc

Comment: @DashWinterson - I was going by: https://gist.github.com/ryantuck/56c5aaa8f9124422ac964629f4c8deb0 and: 
https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2011/10/python-gnupg-gpg-example/

In both docs they use a list of recipients, with only one within. I've tried changing my single string to a list of a single recipient, with still the same result.

Comment: @DashWinterson - I also forgot to say following your comment I tried updating the private_key_recipient to the public key fingerprint, with still the same error message.

Comment: Just looking at the module there appears to be a `trust_keys` method. Does that do what you want?

Comment: it may be (according to the docs) that you need to specify it as a list? https://gnupg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#encryption-and-decryption

Comment: @larsks - Wow. You know, I searched that documentation for "trust" and for some reason didn't see that section. Don't I feel the fool!
Thanks very much! If you post that as a reply I'll mark it as the answer. 
Thanks also to DashWinterson for asking the initial questions and bearing with my answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at `pydoc gnupg` I see:

```
trust_keys(self, fingerprints, trustlevel)
```

It's not documented, but it sounds like what you want.